# Passar parametros entre telas [ionic2 / angular2]

Tags: angular, ionic2

Como passar um parâmetro (id) entre as telas?

Tentei o NavParams, mas não consegui fazer o que eu queria. Gostaria de colocar o ID no ion-item e quando eu clicasse ele mandasse o id para outra tela.

Answer (score 0):

Basta pegar pelo navParams.

Para passar o id faça o seguinte:

```
this.navCtrl.push(TestePage, {id: '1'});
```

Lá na TestePage, você pega com:

```
let id_objeto = this.navParans.get(id);
```

[Documentação IONIC para NavParams](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/)

Comment: Grato lazyFox, pela edição!
Ficou bem explicado agora!